# Jquery .hide function hides things outside the selected class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to jQuery and I'm trying to make sections of a form that will open or close when the header is clicked on.

The header is outside the class `.entrysection` so the header shouldn't be hidden (I think). But when I open the page to view it, the header is hidden thus no toggle to open the sections.

This is an abbreviated version of my page but I think it's enough to demonstrate what I'm trying to do. If I can provide any more helpful information I will.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entrysection').hide();
  $('.sectiontitle h3').toggle(
    function() {
      $(this).next('.entrysection').slideDown();
      $(this).addClass('close');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).next('.entrysection').fadeOut();
      $(this).removeClass('close');
    }
  ); // end toggle
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sectiontitle">
  <h3>A Header</h3>
  <div class="entrysection">
    <p>Some silly unimportant stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sectiontitle">
  <h3>Another Header</h3>
  <div class="entrysection">
    <p>Yet more unimportant stuff</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sectiontitle">
  <h3>Yet Another Header</h3>
  <div class="entrysection">
    <p>The least important stuff yet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `toggle()` doesn't work in this manner any more. It's now only used to hide and show an element. The toggle signature you are using has been deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rory is suggesting the toggle version for alternating clicks is deprecated. What you can do is use use the [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) and [slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) helpers.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.entrysection').hide();
    $('.sectiontitle h3').click(function () {
        $(this).next('.entrysection').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('close');
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <script      
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" 
>
      </script>
     <script>
         $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.entrysection').hide();
  $('.sectiontitle h3').click(function() {
   $(this).next('.entrysection').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('close');

     });
}); // end ready
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3>A Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Some silly unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3>Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Yet more unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
 <div class="sectiontitle"> 
         <h3>Yet Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>The least important stuff yet</p>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h3>A Header</h3>
```

The above H3 is inside a .sectiontitle so it is caught by the

```
$('.sectiontitle h3').toggle()
```

`$('.sectiontitle h3')` means that all `h3`s inside *any* element with the class `sectiontitle` will be toggled: on document load the toggle hides them all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.entrysection').hide();
 $('.sectiontitle h3').toggle(
        function() {
           $(this).next('.entrysection').slideDown();
           $(this).addClass('close');
        },
        function() {
           $(this).next('.entrysection').fadeOut();
           $(this).removeClass('close');
      }
    ); // end toggle
}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3>A Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Some silly unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3>Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Yet more unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
 <div class="sectiontitle"> 
         <h3>Yet Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>The least important stuff yet</p>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
```

### FIX

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.entrysection').hide();

  $('.sectiontitle h3').on('click', function() {
      $('.sectiontitle h3').next('.entrysection').hide();
      
      $(this).next('.entrysection').show();
  });



}); // end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="sectiontitle">
    <h3>A Header</h3>
    <div class="entrysection">
      <p>Some silly unimportant stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sectiontitle">
    <h3>Another Header</h3>
    <div class="entrysection">
      <p>Yet more unimportant stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sectiontitle">
    <h3>Yet Another Header</h3>
    <div class="entrysection">
      <p>The least important stuff yet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
         $(document).ready(function() {
     $( ".sectiontitle h3" ).click(function( event ) {
      var target = $( event.target );
      if ( target.is( "h3" ) ) {
      var par = target.parent();
      par.children().find("p").toggle();
      }
     
    });

}); // end ready
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
      <script      
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" 
>
      </script>
     <script>

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3 >A Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Some silly unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
<div class="sectiontitle">  
         <h3 >Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>Yet more unimportant stuff</p>
            </div>
            </div>
 <div class="sectiontitle"> 
         <h3 >Yet Another Header</h3>
            <div class="entrysection">
                <p>The least important stuff yet</p>
            </div>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> Please try with the above. It has been resolved

Answer (score -1):

The `.toggle()` function itself is hiding the h3. On the [JQuery documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it says `.toggle()` does this:

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

To make it behave the way I'm thinking you want it to. You would instead just add a click handler on the H3 then toggle the `entrysection`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.sectiontitle h3').click(function () {
      $(this).next('.entrysection').toggle('slow')
  });
});
```

Comment: That's a very vague statement @Bhuwan, Explain yourself. I just saw your post and it actually has the same solution aside from using "slow".